# Creating an 'empty' process

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Is it possible to start a process that is 'empty' on Windows? That is, it has all the properties associated with a process such as a PID, registers, state etc. but no mapped memory; not created from an executable.
I'd like to start an entirely clean process from a parent, in which I can map new address spaces, use a debugger on, etc.

Comment: I'm 99% certain this is not possible, every process requires an executable that has an entry point.  That said, you can create a tiny .exe that does nothing, and from there run your own code.  `rundll32` is a decent place to start since all it does is load a DLL and call an entry point.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Zero Threaded Process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7623493/zero-threaded-process)

Comment: @Jeffrey I'm more looking for a process with a thread and no memory. I think Tumbleweed53's answer is the approach I should go for. I'll leave this open to see if anyone knows a way to do this directly.

Comment: A thread has a stack. You cannot have a thread without consuming address space. The closest thing to what you asked for (which may not be precisely what you actually need) would be to spin up a VM and have it boot a custom kernel. Hyper-V lets you deal with the VM part, and writing a bootloader plus a tiny kernel shouldn't take much more than two days.

Comment: That's a good point, I hadn't considered the creation of the stack - I had in mind not mapping any executable/library into the address space.

Comment: That's not supported using the Windows API. It *might* be possible using the [Native API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_API), though that puts you into undocumented/can change at any time without prior notice territory.

Comment: That said, while you cannot create an empty process using the Windows API, there are techniques that allow you to tear out everything from an existing process, such as [process hollowing](https://attack.mitre.org/techniques/T1055/012/). It would probably help if you could describe what you need this for.

Comment: this is partially possible. say [`PssCaptureSnapshot`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processsnapshot/nf-processsnapshot-psscapturesnapshot) do this internally. you can call *[Zw/Nt]CreateProcess* and pass 0 in place *SectionHandle* (usually here must be section created from *exe* file). in this case process address will be inherited from *InheritFromProcessHandle*. this so called "fork" of process. early you even create thread and such process and run it, but now (win 10 , may be win 8 - not check) - you can not create thread in such process